# Android - Query Text in Search view is not rewritten after suggestion selected

Tags: android, search

I am trying to implement a SuggestionProvider for my App. I've made it running, but the issue I face is that after clicking on a suggestion - it's value is not replaced in the Query Text above. Basically - clicking on it - does what is expected, but afterwards - the text in the search view remains the same as what was written by the user, and not what was selected from the suggestion.

in my Search Configuration i have `android:searchMode="queryRewriteFromText"`, and in my SearchProvider i utilize `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY`, and set it to the same value as the value of the Search Suggestion.

Do I need to do something special to get it updated after the click ?

Comment: Use autocompletetextview http://collegewires.com/android/2012/09/android-auto-complete-text-view-example/

Answer (score 2):

Well, now is probably late, but maybe can help someone. Whatever intent you get, you can grab query like this:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
  mSearchView.setQueryText(query, false);
} else if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(namera.getAction())) {
  String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
  mSearchView.setQuery(query, false);
}
```